# Calling function during regular expression replacement

Tags: regex, matlab

I need to decode a string coming from json. Special characters are encoded as hex unicode (e.g. the apostrophe is /u0027).
I'm trying to accomplish this with these expression:

```
regexprep('Can/u0027t add the category','/u(\d{4})',native2unicode(hex2dec(strrep('$1','/u',''))))
```

but I get the following error

```
Error using hex2dec (line 38)
Input string found with characters other than 0-9, a-f, or A-F.
```

because hex2dec receives '$1' as value and not the result of strrep('$1','/u','').
If I try

```
regexprep('Can/u0027t add the category','/u(\d{4})',strrep('$1','/u',''))
```

I get, correctly, 'Can0027t add the category'. If I try with

```
regexprep('Can/u0027t add the category','/u(\d{4})',native2unicode(hex2dec(strrep('/u0027','/u',''))))
```

I get the right result (but with a fixed decoding, obviously).
I don't understand why the result of strrep is not the input argument of hex2dec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're tricking yourself with the debug.  The `$1` expansion in the replacement string operates on the string itself, as seen by regexprep.  It is not expanded by the MATLAB parser before calling any functions, which will just see the string `'$1'`.  If the result of those functions contains a `$1`, it will get passed into regexprep and expanded.  So, for example, your test case with the bare `strrep` replaces nothing (since its input is the string `'$1'`), and passes the bare `$1` string right back into regexprep.

You have two issues.  One is easy: you don't need `strrep` at all, since the parentheses mark just the hex digits as the token.  `$1` expands with no `/u`.  Test it:

```
regexprep('Can/u0027t add the category','/u(\d{4})','$1')
```

results in 'Can0027t add the category'.

Now for the harder one.  As previously noted, you can't call normal functions on the `$1` and have them do anything.  However, MATLAB provides a special regexp syntax to call functions from *inside* the replacement string.  Here is the documentation:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/dynamic-regular-expressions.html

In summary, `${cmd($1)}` expands to calling the MATLAB function `cmd` on the replacement token to generate the replacement string.  So putting it all together:

```
regexprep('Can/u0027t add the category', '/u(\d{4})', '${native2unicode(hex2dec($1))}')
```

ans = Can't add the category